# How do I set the -maxLength option of Stanford parser in python

Tags: java, python, parsing, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm using the python interface of Stanford parser. I want to skip the long sentences when doing the parsing job. So I use:

```
path1 = '/usr/local/Cellar/stanford-parser/3.4/libexec/stanford-parser.jar'
path2 = '/usr/local/Cellar/stanford-parser/3.4/libexec/stanford-parser-3.4-models.jar'
parser = StanfordParser(path_to_jar = path1, path_to_models_jar = path2, java_options = '-maxLength50')
```

But it says:

```
Unrecognized option: -maxLength50
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

Then I tried:

```
parser = StanfordParser(path_to_jar = path1, path_to_models_jar = path2, java_options = '-maxLength=50')
```

It still says

```
Unrecognized option: -maxLength=50
```

The following option works well though:

```
parser = StanfordParser(path_to_jar = path1, path_to_models_jar = path2, java_options = '-mx20000m')
```

But I keep running out of memory if I don't set the maximum length of sentences, even if the '-mx20000m' is set. So I guess I really need to skip some long sentences.

Can anyone tell me how do I set the '-maxLength' option in python? Thanks!!

Comment: Which python interface is this?

Comment: @Max I'm using nltk, from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser

Answer (score 2):

The java options are really options to the JVM, not to the Stanford parser. You cannot set the java options.

I don't see an option to set maxLen in http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/stanford.html.

How about this in python: if (len(sentence.split())>50: continue

Isn't this a lot simpler?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing instead. Thanks, Max.